# What is a difference between isDemo() and AccountInfoInteger( ACCOUNT_TRADE_MODE )?

Tags: algorithmic-trading, mql4, metatrader4

I noticed that there are sometimes more than one function that produce the same output (or similar).  In this case [`isDemo()`](https://docs.mql4.com/check/isdemo) and [`AccountInfoInteger( ACCOUNT_TRADE_MODE )`](https://docs.mql4.com/account/accountinfointeger)

But the question is are the functions checked the same way? Do they both check the same types of information to verify demo status?

They both may be able to tell me if the active trading account is a Demo account, so when would you use one function over the other?

Are there any other functions that check for a demo status or could be used to check for demo status in MetaTrader Terminal 4, that I haven't found?

Answer (score 0):

### No,
rather do not expect other functions to deliver the same thing.

The observed duality came out from a process of re-forming the historical grounds of the **`MQL4`** language into something newer and closer the **`MQL5`** domain.

When to use the one and when to use the other? Not any easy answer for such dilemma. Guess the old code ought work for at least some time forth, the newer syntax of the ***New-*`MQL4`** has a bit lower probability of becoming unsupported in the compiler-phase ( if compared to the *"old-&-good"*-**`MQL4`** )

Comment: MQ support desk didn't provide much clarification either:  "...If You want to check whether the account is demo, you should use `isDemo()`, for other cases use `AccountInfoInteger()`..."  But it seems to clarify that `isDemo()` wont be depreciated anytime soon.

Comment: Using an experience **from Critical System Design** ( a **NASA Space Shuttle control-technology** being an example of implementation thereof ), one may test, whether **both** the `isDemo()` and `AccountInfoInteger(...)` return the same value and handle as an exception the case, when not.